# How to make two references to one object

Tags: javascript

I'm running the following code:

```
function Status(type) {
  this.type = type;
}


var race = new Status('race');
var status = race;
console.log(status);
console.log(race);
```

and the result is

```
[object Object]
Status {type: "race"}
```

Why are status and race giving different results?  The '==' comparison returns true, whereas the '===' comparison returns false; how can I make status and race point to the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `status` is actually a string while the value of `race` is an object.

If you use the `typeof` operator on both variables, you will discover this.

I think this is happening because **status is reserved** for [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I realize; how do I give them the same value?  I want them pointing to the same object, so that changing status will change race as well.

Comment: @Edylk try my answer also

Comment: Thanks, changing the variable name fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running into a conflict with [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

Change the variable name or put things into a non-global scope.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me and returns the same object in both the instance.

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2932rav/)

Are you trying to run this in a browser console? If yes, it might be causing a conflict with the `window` object in global scope.

Comment: This answer is not incorrect. Not all browsers convert the set value to `status` variable into a string.

Comment: why was my answer downvoted? I provided a jsfiddle with code to prove my point. If you do not agree then you can post a comment on why you think it is wrong.

Comment: @chackerian No I meant what I wrote :p

Comment: @chackerian It was downvotes so I wrote it that way. I should have written 'This answer is not completely incorrect...'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct the only problem is there are some issues as status is already a global variable in JS(window object), this should work fine.

```
function Status(type) {
  this.type = type;
}


var race = new Status('race');
var status2 = race;
console.log(status2);
console.log(race);
```

See this for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status , whenever you assign any value to status it automatically converts that value to string, that was the reason your condition why you were seeing two different object one was string and one was object.

Answer (score 0):

You are use a the same name that you use for *Object* and for *var*, you only need change the name for the *var* that you use
Something like:

```js
function Status(type) {
      this.type = type;
    }

var race = new Status('race');
var getStatus = race;
console.log(getStatus);
console.log(race);
```

> Result: {   "type": "race" } {   "type": "race" }